# How to integrate Linkedin,facebook,twitter in ipad or iphone?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios-simulator

Hi i want to integrate facebook,twitter and linkedin in iphone.I dont know coding for this to happen.Please tell me where the sample codes are available or tel me how to do this.......please help me

Edit:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alekhya you can follow steps from http://developer.linkedin.com/message/6350#6350

TwitterEngine : https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

LinkedInIphone : https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

Facebook iOS SDK : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestions.I will try and let you know

Comment: currently am also working... and have a issue if using twitter and linkedin together .. please check if you have any idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259747 ....

Comment: I followed 7 steps and imported shareviewcontroller.h and .m file.But i got 26 errors..

Comment: what are the errors ... if you can upload the screenshot of error anywhere and give me image link

Comment: for twitter,these links may help u http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_libraries#objectivec    http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/how-to-integrate-twitter-in-your-iphone-t1836.html

Comment: ok,i will upload the screen shot and give u

Comment: I have no issue in twitter .. it working fine with facebook but not working with linkedin

Comment: i added screenshot to my question

Comment: Please check that screenshot and suggest me what should i do...

Comment: just follow it... http://db.tt/yhGQpGQ

Comment: http://developer.linkedin.com/message/6350#6350

Comment: I followed that video.but no use..Can u suggest me any other way to solve this?

Comment: what is name of folder in which your project... be sure folder name has no space.. user underscore instead of space

Comment: In my project I made another folder named "libs".In this folder,i copied LinkedInClientLibrary and OAuthConsumeriPhoneLib.I think there are no such issues.

Comment: copy paste the folder LinkedInClientLibrary and OAuthConsumeriPhoneLib into you project folder… open folder LinkedInClientLibrary… drag drop LinkedIn.bundle and LinkedInClientLibrary.xcodeproj into your project left panel …click on LinkedInClientLibrary.xcodeproj and check the checkbox under libLinkedInClientLibrary.a (topright panel) .. select your project from target and get info by right click and open general tab and add direct dependency by click on + and then set the header search path etc

Comment: ok than make sure you are giving correct HEADER SEARCH PATH

Comment: and make sure these checked things http://db.tt/Zlxu72t http://db.tt/fCv1MkL

Comment: ok,thank u so much,i will check my app thoroughly with your suggestions and let u know

Comment: My problem get solved..The problem is in header search path.Thank u so much for your suggestions

Comment: your welcome.. please accept the answer... and if you can help me in my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259747

Comment: today i too got the same issue..twitter+linkedin not working well.If u solved your issue,please help me out

Comment: hmm make sure about the HEADER SEARCH PATH is correct..... and also please check the post if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297783/

Answer (score 3):

Hi you need to integrate the APIs provided by the social networking websites

You can explore these links and implement the functionality as per your requirements

Facebook:[Facebook APIs and documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

LinkedIn:[LinkedIn APIs and documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/index.jspa)

Twitter :[Twitter APIs and documentation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554679/Twitter-API-Documentation)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer...but really i cant find any examples in this documentations.In my iphone app,i  need to update status of a linkedin network.Please tell me any sample code for this.Thank u in advance

Comment: You can find a very good example for LinkedIn status update at https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone...Cheers

Comment: I checked that example now,But when i try to run the xcode,Authorization is not done.An empty page with  navigation controller appears and in the demo view controller,the consumer key secret key is not given,they are declared as empty strings.is this the problem?I dont know what to do to get this....thanks in advance

Comment: If anyone know how to integrate linkedin in iphone,please help me

Comment: Dude you need to setup details of your app in the LinkedIn developers portal in order to get the consumer secret key and then fill up those keys in the sample code...

Comment: ok sir,i will try and let u know what happpened,Sorry for replying now

Comment: Sir,i downloaded the sample code from github and i entered consumer and secret keys.Its working well.But when i try to do it in a new project,its not possible.how to add libraries and frameworks of lionkedin?Please tell me how to add linkedin library and oauthconsumer frameworks

Comment: In the DemoViewController,rdEngine file is not imported correctly.there is an error saying no such file or directory.but i added linkedin client library xcode as well as linkedin client library in a folder.what to do?any help?

Comment: Hi All I have related issue can you please help me... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259747